# Create a server in Android application

Tags: android, http, soap

I have a client in an android application on my mobile that sends SOAP request to a server .
I have created a server on my PC using tomcat ,servlets that responds to the SOAP request.
I now want both client and server inside same mobile.

Thus,I want to port the same server to an android application on my phone.I am not sure how to do it. How to receive clients request in doPost() method as done in servlets inside my android application that will act as server.

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a port of the Jetty server/servlet container for Android called [I-Jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/). I haven't used it myself but that would allow you to run a servlet container on Android – which is exactly what you need

> to receive clients request in doPost() method as done in servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I'd also like to offer [**Tiny Java Web Server (TJWS)**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tjws):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tjws

It is Servlet 3.0 Spec compatible, and sees production use within [JBOSS's RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/tjws/TJWSServletServer.html) product.

TJWS is BSD licensed and can be compile for Android.